# Can I just rinse the knife & cutting board, instead of washing it, after cutting washed vegetables?

Tags: food-safety

I was wondering something I can't seem to Google anywhere, concerning food safety/hygiene.

And that is whether I can just rinse the cutting board/knife, after cutting up some washed vegetables (e.g. cucumber & tomatoes) or whether doing so could be quite unhygienic and I ought to just wash it every time

• By rinse I mean to just let water run on the knife and cutting board vertically

• And by wash, I mean use a detergent with a sponge or a brush

Comment: It depends on whether is is commercial food prep or home food prep.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Hey, thanks for comment. It's home food prep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a general food safety rule/best practice, you should still perform active washing, rather than passive rinsing, even for fruits and vegetables.

Fruits and vegetables are still vectors for food borne illness and cross contamination. Wide scale recalls of vegetables due to listeria and e. coli are [not uncommon](https://www.newsweek.com/vegetable-recall-100-products-listeria-contamination-fears-1469567). Active washing with soap and water will combat this. A quick swipe with a soapy cloth followed by a rinse will clean up much better than rinsing alone.

Fruits and vegetables also contain things such as sugars, which passive rinsing may not fully clean. This can result in spoilage and/or mold growth on your cutting board. A great demonstration of this would be to cut beets, which have both relatively high sugar and an accompanying red color, and passively rinse up vs actively washing. Washing will clean up much better. The same is true for other fruits and vegetables, though the lack of red dye makes it less easy to notice.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. This... changes everything.

Comment: Would probably be best to create another thread for this, but would say that the same would apply for a 'shaker bottle', used solely for whey with milk? I.e. whether adequately rinsing it would be enough, or it'd still be kind of 'risky'?

Comment: @ValeriLagunov Even more so - now you added proteins and especially fats to the equation.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks for the comment. Yeah, that makes sense. Still quite a bummer to have to do it each time... oh well

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can just rinse it.

Personally, I just rinse it under water after prepping fruits and vegetables, and when cutting meat I rinse and use [coarse salt and lemon](https://www.realsimple.com/home-organizing/cleaning/cleaning-kitchen/cleaning-wood-cutting-boards) to give it a gentle scrub.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the reply. Think the main reason for my concern, was due to the cutting board, smelling a bit of the said vegetables, hence perhaps a bit of bacteria, developing over time.